# How to access Items of listView from other window

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

My problems is concerned about ListView which one I have in my MainWindow (using C# 4.5 and WPF xaml).

I have created function (in MainWindow) which is reloading instances from List myList to my myListView. 
However I can not make this method static, neither call this method from other window file. On the other hand I am able to call this function from MainWindow.xaml.cs file.

What I want to do is have a ready method to call (from entire solution) which will clear the properties Items of myListView (in MainWindow). Further, the function will add every instance of myClass from myList to the listView.

There is some code to visualize better what I mean:

```
public static List<MyClass> myList = new List<SingleThought>();

public void ReloadFunction()
{
    this.myListView.Items.Clear();
    foreach (MyClass myClass in myList)
        this.myListView.Items.Add(myClass);
}
```

Please ask if I have not described enough well.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the function itself as a parameter to the child class.
In the MainWindow:

```
ChildWindow child = new ChildMyWindow(ReloadFunction);
```

In the ChildWindow (or any other class):

```
class ChildWindow
{
    public Action reloadonmain;

    ChildWindow(Action _reloadonmain)
    {
        reloadonmain = _reloadonmain
    }

    ReloadButtonClick()
    {
        reloadonmain();
    }
}
```

PS. In wpf you would likely be best served by binding your [ListView to an ObservableCollection](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/56322/ListView-ComboBox-and-ObservableCollection-T). This will remove the need for reloads.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to pass a pointer from one window to the other, you can decouple your code using the mediator pattern. We've been using this method in our code and it works great. This may be overkill for you, but this scales well and keeps code decoupled.

First, define a message enum and a mediator class

```
enum Messages
{
    Clear
}


class Mediator
{
     public static Mediator Instance = new Mediator();
     public void Register(Message message, Action callback);
     public void BroadcastMessage(Message message);
}
```

I'll leave the implementation details to you, but the mediator class maintains a Dictionary<Message,List<Action>>.

In your main window's constructor you register for the clear message

```
Mediator.Instance.Register(Messages.Clear,ReloadFunction);
```

This adds the ReloadFunction Action to the dictionary with the Key of "Messages.Clear". Now anywhere else in your code, you can clear the list by calling

```
Mediator.Instance.BroadcastMessage(Messages.Clear);
```

Which will iterate over all Actions registered to the clear method and call them.